# Azure, CloudFlare and Cache, Content wont update

Tags: git, azure, caching, ftp, cloudflare

I'm running a classic asp site on an Azure Web app, with DNS and caching through CloudFlare.  I've updated an asp file's html and deployed through Git but the change isn't coming through in the browser.

This is what i have done to try to get it updated, without success. Is there anything i can try?

- Purged single file through CloudFlare,
- Purged everything,
- Put in dev mode,
- Created a subdomain bypassing cloudflare and attached to Azure website,
- Uploaded the file again through ftp,
- Downloaded file from ftp and compared to local (confirmed the same),
- Added a cache control to the web.config to ignore this file
- Restarted the web app,
- Cleared browser cache,
- Confirmed a status of 200 (not a cached file) is being delivered,
- Tested with IE to 'check for a new file on every visit'.

But still the old content is loading.

I checked with Cloudflare support but since the site is bypassing Cloudflare (made sure the the orange cloud is grey) its can't be a cache issue with them.

This is getting pretty frustrating. Oh, its been going on nearly a week so it's from lack of patience waiting for cache timeouts.

cheers

Comment: Are you using AppCache? If so, what does the file look like?

Comment: This has finally been sorted. Apparently it was a issue with CloudFlare even though i was bypassing them!  It will no doubt continue to happen :(  oh and no to AppCache.  Its a pretty basic .asp file with modified html.

Comment: Thanks for following up and keep us in the loop!